# How to resolve implicit lookup by bounded generic?

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, context-bound

I have a series of class Foo:

```
trait Foo
class Foo1 extends Foo
class Foo2 extends Foo
//...
```

and I have a type class and instances for all of the Foos:

```
trait CanBar[T] { def bar: Unit }
implicit val foo1: CanBar[Foo1] = null
implicit val foo2: CanBar[Foo2] = null
```

and I try to get the type class instance from a method:

```
def bar[T <: Foo](foo: T) = {
  val canBar = implicitly[CanBar[T]]
  //...
}
```

The compiler complains `No implicits found for parameter e: CanBar[T]`, even though I imported all the `CanBar[Foo]` instances.

My assumption is that the compiler is looking for T (which is Any or Foo) and did not find any. Am I correct and how can I make it work in this case (without macros)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The compiler complains `No implicits found for parameter e: CanBar[T]`, even though I imported all the `CanBar[Foo]` instances.

`CanBar[Foo]` is not `CanBar[T]`.

Add context bound

```
def bar[T <: Foo : CanBar](foo: T) = {
  val canBar = implicitly[CanBar[T]]
  //...
}
```

Comment: In this case I believe it would be better to `def bar[T <: Foo](foo: T)(implicit canBar: CanBar[T]) = {`. This way, the implicitly line is not required.