# Play-JSON cannot find implicit Writes[T] for type parameter T

Tags: scala, play-json

I'm new to Scala and still learning about most of the features.
I'm trying to convert a Dataset[T] to Json.
I'm using json play to create implicit Writes.
Type parameters work fine when I load my Dataset:

```
def processEvent[T](spark: SparkSession, inputPath: String)(implicit encoder: Encoder[T]): Unit = {
  val ds = spark.read.parquet(inputPath).as[T]
  ds.collect().foreach { event =>
    val serializedEvent = eventToJson[T](spark, event)
    postEvent(serializedEvent)
  }
}
```

But in the call to `EventToJson`, I get the error: `No Json serializer found for type T. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.`

```
def eventToJson[T](spark: SparkSession, event: T): String = {
  Json.toJson(event).toString()
}
```

When I replace the parameterized type with one of my case classes, the code works fine:

```
def eventToJson(spark: SparkSession, event: MyCaseClass): String = {
  Json.toJson(event).toString()
}
```

Why doesn't the parameterized type find the corresponding case class and implicit Writes?

Comment: I would recommend to read some tutorial about [Scala implicit](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html) [Play JSON](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonCombinators)

Comment: @DesireeCox Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to constrain `T` with a context bound:

```
def eventToJson[T: Writes](spark: SparkSession, event: T): String = {
  Json.toJson(event).toString()
}
```

or

```
def eventToJson[T: Format](spark: SparkSession, event: T): String = {
  Json.toJson(event).toString()
}
```

Then probably you'll have to add the same context bound to `processEvent`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, SparkSession}
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, Writes}

def processEvent[T: Encoder: Writes](spark: SparkSession, inputPath: String): Unit = {
  val ds = spark.read.parquet(inputPath).as[T]
  ds.collect().foreach { event =>
    val serializedEvent = eventToJson[T](spark, event)
    postEvent(serializedEvent)
  }
}

def eventToJson[T: Writes](spark: SparkSession, event: T): String = {
  Json.toJson(event).toString()
}
```

> Why doesn't the parameterized type find the corresponding case class and implicit Writes?

Because it is defined for the case class, not for `T` (even though `T` can become the type of case class when you apply `eventToJson`).

In Scala if a definition of method `foo` produces compile error that an implicit of type `Bar` is not found then you can try to add that implicit to the signature of `foo`

```
def foo(implicit bar: Bar) = ???
```

In this way you postpone resolution of implicit till the time when `foo` is called.

If the type is parametric

```
def foo[T](implicit bar: Bar[T]) = ???
```

this can be rewritten with a context bound

```
def foo[T: Bar] = ???
```

[Typeclasses methods called in functions with type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57675918/typeclasses-methods-called-in-functions-with-type-parameters)

[How to resolve implicit lookup by bounded generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57495884/how-to-resolve-implicit-lookup-by-bounded-generic)

[Implicit Encoder for TypedDataset and Type Bounds in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55637342/implicit-encoder-for-typeddataset-and-type-bounds-in-scala)